# Splitting MAC address on python

Tags: python-2.7, split, mac-address

I have a MAC address that I have to manipulate just a little.

I wish to convert `"FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF"` to `"FF FF FF FF FF FF"`.

How can it be done?

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: There's no need to tag 'Pycharm' questions that only relate to doing something in Python, I removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a string, simply replace all `:` characters with a space:

```
>>> mac = 'FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF'
>>> spacemac = mac.replace(':',' ')
>>> spacemac
'FF FF FF FF FF FF'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned split, first split it and then join it:

```
' '.join('FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF'.split(':'))
```